# Quasi linear PDE 1st order

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have a problem with the following PDE:

[image: PDE]

I tried to solve it, but I get stuck at this point:

[image: S]

Comment: Exactly, I only paremetrized with s, so I had x'(s)=s, y'(s)=(x(s)/(w(s)*s)) and w(s)=u so w'(s)=-w(s). As you can see I tried to solve for x(s) and w(s), the only problem I face is in y'(s) part. The Integral I marked is where I have a problem, do you have a suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you for the correction. That means: x(s)=c_1*e^s and w(s)=c_3*e^-s. Now y'(s)=(c_1*e^2s)/(c_3*y(s)), is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The general solution must satisfy the following equation (Mathematica tells this):
$$f_1\left(x u(x,y),\frac{y^2 u(x,y)-x}{2 u(x,y)}\right)=0$$
with $f_1(x,y)$ an arbitrary function.

We choose by trial $f_1(x,y)=x\cdot y$, hence

$$\text{f1}\left(x u(x,y),\frac{y^2 u(x,y)-x}{2 u(x,y)}\right)=\frac{1}{2} x \left(y^2 u(x,y)-x\right)=0$$

The solution which satisfies the PDE is then: $\mathbf{u(x,y)=\frac{x}{y^2}}$

And also $u(x^2,x)=1$ satisfies the boundary condition.

Comment: Thank you, but the question should be solved via the method of characteristics. I tried to use the method of characteristics but I couldn't proceed

Comment: Sorry, but your image is almost unreadable.